# NodeJs not able to listen to port on digital ocean Ubuntu

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, socket.io, laravel-5.1

I am trying to implement messaging on my server .Which is Ubuntu 14.04/Nginx

I have installed

```
1.nodejs 
2.Redis
3.laravel
```

all successfully

when I run command

```
node -v
```

its giving me the version of node

in my controller my code look like this

```
public function sendMessage(){

        $redis = LRedis::connection();
        $redis->publish('message', 'Sending Message to Port');
        return redirect('writemessage');
    }
```

and my server.js code is like this

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(8890);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log("new client connected");
  var redisClient = redis.createClient();
  redisClient.subscribe('message');

  redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
    console.log("mew message in queue "+ message + "channel");
    socket.emit(channel, message);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    redisClient.quit();
  });

});
```

The Redis server is running on  default 6379

and to listen to listen to the broadcast my socket.php file has following code

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>

    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8890');
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
            $( "#messages" ).append( "<p>"+data+"</p>" );
          });
    </script>
```

Everything is running fine but I don't see any message on the socket.php page

Any Idea how to debug this

the same works fine on Localhost

**Update**

So I did

`redis-cli monitor`

and tried to execute my code again I can see redis is broadcasting the messages like this

```
1458128671.226586 [0 127.0.0.1:59112] "SELECT" "0"
1458128671.232152 [0 127.0.0.1:59112] "PUBLISH" "message" "Sending Message to Port"
```

but on node side I don't receive it

Please!! help me

Comment: Is your node server running successfully on production(Digtial ocean) ??

Comment: @Drudge without any error I its running , Also I did `redis-cli monitor` I can see my messages being published like this `1458128671.226586 [0 127.0.0.1:59112] "SELECT" "0"
1458128671.232152 [0 127.0.0.1:59112] "PUBLISH" "message" "Sending Message to Port"   But node is not receiving it 
`

Comment: Did you try to visit the url:with port ?

Comment: In my guess,  node server is not running  .

Comment: Drudge this is the url , `http://dev.iclock.in/writemessage` and you can listen to it on `http://dev.iclock.in/socket` , In my code I have removed the input value and hard coded the message string ,

Comment: You should check your console mate, i  find this "GET http://localhost:8890/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1458129334437-3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @Drudge can you tell me what command to run in the console to check if the node server is runing or not , I usually do this `node server.js` and then in the console it will wait for the messages that are sent and I could see them there in my localhost

Comment: If you run as `node server.js` it will only run until you are logged in your console mate . You have to use PM2 package to run node server . Check this [link] (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106459/discussion-between-vikram-and-drudge).

Answer (score 0):

Digital Ocean by default close all ports except :80

You need to open the ports first. You can find the solution here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41408983/4556995