# Sockets.IO only works in localhost

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, socket.io, digital-ocean

Here's my codes

```
const brokerService = require('socket.io')({
    path: '/broker',
    serveClient: false
});

exports.assignServices = function ()
{
    brokerService.listen(3003);
}

brokerService.on("connection" , (client) => {
    console.log("connected");

    client.on("test" , (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });

    client.on("add" , (data) => {
        console.log(data); 
    });
})
```

I use application called socket-io-tester on my MAC

it sends packets to my localhost with this URL (http://127.0.0.1.com:3003/broker)

and my application logged "Connected" - works now

but after uploading my app to digitalocean servers , it does not work anymore

with the same app I send to the same URL , but replacing the ip to my domain name (http://domainName.com:3003/broker)

it does not work ?

same code / same URL request / same application I use to test

may the issue with my server?

I turned off the firewall , is it related anyway ?

Comment: if anyone faced the same issue : DigitalOcean by default close all ports , you have to open it manually : this answer solved my issue : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41408983/13078248

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socket.io does not work on the ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546617/socket-io-does-not-work-on-the-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @O.Jones Yes - exactly